# retieve value of a field and display it cakephp

Tags: database, cakephp

I am new to cakephp, I want to get a valu from a table in database (the value of coordinate_x) and display it. Let's say coordinate_x is now at 10, I want to display the value "10". How do i do this in cakephp? here is my  code:

```
 $coordinate_x = $this->find('list', array(
            'fields' => array('coordinate_x'),
            'conditions' => array('id' => $fighterId))); 

 echo "" & $coordinate_x;
```

Now, what is displaying is 0 instead of the actual value of the coordinate. Anyone please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The find, if successful, will return an array, so you won't be able to echo out the result. Use cake's convenience **pr** function to see how the data has been returned (instead of the echo):

```
pr($coordinate_x);
```

Once you see the structure of the array, you can call it, something like:

```
$coordinate_x['YourModel']['coordinate_x'];
```

Comment: Thank you. But if I need it tobe displayed as a message? is there any other way to retrieve the value and display it apart from what I already did?

Comment: Edited the answer, what is the name of your model?

Comment: Thank you again!!! your new answer just gave me the idea!!! so I went like this:

$datas = $this->read(null, $fighterId);   echo $datas['Fighter']['coordinate_x'];             and it worked!